# multiline string to a variable in a helm template?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to assign a multiline string to a variable in a helm template?

I have a variable as follows:

```
{{- $fullDescription := "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -}}
```

but I would prefer to keep it in my code base as

```
{{- $fullDescription :|- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -}}
```

.. but this is not valid yaml.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I worked around this issue by including the content I require from a separate file.

Eg.

```
  fullDescription: |-
{{ .Files.Get files/description.html | indent 4 }}
```

Comment: how does this even work? I get the same error using this style like from answer below.

Answer (score 20):

## Input

values.yaml

```
myFile: |
  This is a multiline
  value, aka heredoc.

myArray:
  - key1=value1
  - key2=value2
```

configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myTemplate
data:
  myFile: {{- .Values.myFile | toYaml | indent 1 }}
  myArray: |
  {{- range $k, $v := .Values.myArray }}
    - {{ . | toYaml | indent 4 | trim }}
  {{- end }}
```

## Output

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: myTemplate
data:
  myFile: |
   This is a multiline
   value, aka heredoc.
  myArray: |
    - key1=value1
    - key2=value2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work like this:

```
$fullDescription: | +
   "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me. I get `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on x/y/z.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 15: did not find expected comment or line break`

Answer (score 0):

You could've used `values.yaml`, which would save you from adding an extra file.

```
fullDescription: |+
  line1
  line2
```

then in template

```
fullDescription: |
{{ $fullDescription | indent 2}}
```

Probably not you wanted, but you could use newline char

```
{{- $fullDescription := "a\nb\nc\n" -}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @geliba187 works. It has to mention that declaring the variable $fullDescription is needed.

A solution without an extra files looks completely like this:

values.yaml

```
fullDescription: |+
line1
line2
```

in template

```
{{ $fullDescription := .Values.fullDescription }}
fullDescription: |
{{ $fullDescription | indent 2}}
```