# Insert multiline json string into helm template for base64 encoding

Tags: json, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I am trying to insert multiline json string into helm template for base64 encoding required for Kubernetes secret.

Goals:

- helm value is injected into json string
- multi-line json string must be base64 encoded using `b64enc`

`myfile1.json` does not work but `myfile2.json` works.
I prefer not to put entire json file in `values.yaml`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "mychart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "mychart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "mychart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
type: Opaque
data:
  myfile.json: {{ |-
    {
      "item1": {
          "name": "{{ .Values.item1.name }}"
      },
      "item2": {
      }
    } | b64enc }}
  myfile2.json: {{ .Values.myfile2 | b64enc }}
```

Answer (score 46):

You actually don't need to base64-encode the secret in the helm chart. If you use the `stringData` field instead of `data` field, Kubernetes knows that it needs to base64 encode the data upon the secret's deployment.

From the docs ([Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-manually)):

> The Secret contains two maps: `data` and `stringData`. The `data` field is used to store arbitrary data, encoded using base64. The `stringData` field is provided for convenience, and allows you to provide secret data as unencoded strings.

So we can rewrite your secret using `stringData` instead of `data` and keep multiline json strings in templates like so:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "Secret"
metadata:
  name: {{ template "mychart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "mychart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "mychart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
type: "Opaque"
stringData:
  myfile.json: |-
    {
      "item1": {
          "name": "{{ .Values.item1.name }}"
      },
      "item2": {
      }
    }
  myfile2.json: {{ .Values.myfile2 }}
```

Note that this does not mean you suddenly need to worry about having unencoded secrets. `stringData` will ultimately be base64-encoded and converted to `data` when it is installed, so it will behave exactly the same once it's loaded into Kubernetes.

Again, from the docs **(emphasis mine)** ([Source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#secret-v1-core)):

> `stringData` allows specifying non-binary secret data in string form. **It is provided as a write-only convenience method.** All keys and values are merged into the `data` field on write, overwriting any existing values. **It is never output when reading from the API.**

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution. You can use tpl function on json file to render template.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ template "mychart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "mychart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "mychart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
type: Opaque
data:
  myfile.json: {{ tpl(.Files.Get "myfile.json") . | b64enc }}
```

myfile.json

```
{
  "item1": {
    "name": "{{ .Values.item1.name }}"
  },
  "item2": {
  }
}
```

Comment: While using `stringData` as mentioned in the highest upvoted answer is good enough for most use-cases, I hope this will be voted higher because that solution is not the correct answer for every case. This solution is great for my case, as I already have a base64 encoded string I wanted to use directly. The string is stored in a file that's accessible to my CI jobs, so this solution allows me to read the file in directly to the `data` field without it becoming encoded a second time, and without having to decode the file to read it in.

Comment: This solution is also perfect if you plan to keep editing the inserted file in a proper editor, with syntax check, highlighting etc - or maybe it's even a binary (image etc)

Answer (score 6):

My impression [(and others seem to have hit it too)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50951124/multiline-string-to-a-variable-in-a-helm-template) is you have to compromise either on it being multi-line or on not putting it in a file. I think the problem is that you have to use a yaml instruction (the `|-`) to get multiple lines and that is part of the template itself so you can't get an 'output' from it in a way that you can then feed into `b64enc`.

If this were a ConfigMap you wouldn't need to feed into `b64enc` so it would be as simple as:

```
  myfile.json: |
    {
      "item1": {
          "name": "{{ .Values.item1.name }}"
      },
      "item2": {
      }
    }
```

Or if you were to compromise on single-line approach then that could be:

`myfile.json: {{ tpl ("{ 'item1': { 'name': '{{ .Values.item1.name }}' }, 'item2': { } }") . | toJson | b64enc }}`

If it were coming from a file then you could use `{{ tpl (.Files.Get "files/myfile.json") . | b64enc | quote }}`

Another option would be to [put the whole json in the values file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54038837/how-to-pass-entire-json-string-to-helm-chart-value)

Or you could have a `myfile` entry in your values file like:

```
myfile:
  item1:
    name: "bob"
  item2:
    name: "fred"
```

And then use it with `myfile.json: {{ .Values.myfile | toJson | b64enc }}`